# Unity3D Rigidbodies acts like objects is elastic and falling inside eachother

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I was making a game about stacking objects on top of eachother but when I spawn a new object above it falls inside in other object and behaves like elastic material.

I didn't specify any Physics Material to the Rigidbody, It's just a vanilla Rigidbody component.

[Here is a gif about my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBOz8.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten to add a Box collider to the cube prefab.

Comment: It's already has, otherways it will be not collide with ground.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the collision detection method on the rigidbody is set to either continuous or continuous dynamic. Make sure there's a collider as well.

Comment: I tried to set that detection method but didn't change anything else.